# Check if user has perms?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I tried doing this:

```
if(!msg.author.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES')) return msg.channel.send(":x: You don't have permissions. :x:")
```

but it gave me this error:

```
TypeError: msg.author.hasPermission is not a function
```

Help? (Tring to check if the user has permission to manage messages when a specific code is executed.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use discordjs, v13 you can do like below:

```js
    if(message.member.permissions.has(Discord.Permissions.FLAGS.ADMINISTRATOR)) {
        /* logic here */
    }
```

All Permission Flags are under this property `Discord.Permissions.FLAGS`

Answer (score 3):

Users don't have permissions, guild members do

you need to get the user as a guild member with

```js
const member = message.guild.member(message.author);
```

so do this

```js
if(!message.guild.member(message.author).hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES')) {
  return msg.channel.send(":x: You don't have permissions. :x:") 
}
```